# Is there a way to send one packet to multiple recipients in UDP without using multicast?

Tags: sockets

I've read other questions like this but they bring up multicast and that's usually the correct answer. But my problem is I don't have access to the client so I can not control them "subscribing" to a multicast group.

Is there any solution where the client decides which recipients to send the one packet and the router forwards it to said recipients? (Without the recipients having to do anything on their part)

The reason I am asking is because I have smart lights that I can control, and instead of looping through and sending to each individually I was hoping there was a technology that I could utilize to make this process more efficient

Comment: Are all the devices on the same network segment?  A simple broadcast message should work in that case.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for your reply! Yes they are on the same network segment. I've actually been thinking about using broadcast. My program would send about 20 packets/messages per second to the broadcast and didn't know if that is considered too "chatty" for broadcast use.

Comment: If the alternative would be sending 20*numberOfDevices non-broadcast packets per second, that's hardly too chatty.  But 20 Hz seems an absurdly high update rate for lights, unless you're *trying* to induce seizures in people...  If the goal is just to get smooth transitions between light levels, see if the lights' command set includes some sort of ramp command.

Comment: "*Is there any solution where the client decides which recipients to send the one packet and the router forwards it to said recipients?*" - that is exactly what multicast is meant for. You send a single packet to the multicast group, and the router forwards to only the recipients that have subscribed to that group. But, if your recipients don't support multicasting, then your only options (assuming no ramp-like command) are 1) broadcasting the packet to the entire subnet (IPv4 only), or 2) sending duplicates of the packet to every individual recipient one at a time.